# Getting server 500 internal error in Postman but error not show in the spring suite tools Console

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I am trying to execute a registration method having te API:
**http://localhost:100/api/v1/registration/connect**
When I run the front-end and the back-end and inspect the source code, I receive an internal server error 500
[Internal Server Error 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAfYy.png)

Regarding this, I went to check the Spring Tools Suite Console to check where the issue is but I found no error there. I need to see the error in the console to figure out the problem.
This is the method where I receive an error:

```js
@Override
public String login(LoginRequest request) { //updated recently
  if (userRepo.findByEmail(request.getEmail()).isPresent() && passwordEncoder
    .matches(request.getPassword(), userRepo.findByEmail1(request.getEmail()).get().getPassword())) {

    String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(
      token,
      LocalDateTime.now(),
      LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(5),
      userRepo.findByEmail1(request.getEmail()).get()
    );

    confirmationTokenService.saveConfirmationToken(
      confirmationToken);
    t = confirmationToken.getExpiresAt();
    emailSender.send(request.getEmail(), buildEmail(userRepo.findByEmail1(request.getEmail()).get().getFirstName(), token));

    return "{" +
      "\n\"text\" :\"Utilisateur connecté avec succès, voici le token de connexion\"," + token + "\"," +
      "\n\"email\" :\"" + userRepo.findByEmail1(request.getEmail()).get().getEmail() + "\"," +
      "\n\"Role\" :\"" + userRepo.findByEmail1(request.getEmail()).get().getRoles().toString() + "\"," +
      "\n\"first_name\" : \"" + userRepo.findByEmail1(request.getEmail()).get().getFirstName() + "\"," +
      "\n\"Enabled\" : " + userRepo.findByEmail1(request.getEmail()).get().getEnabled() +
      "}";

  }

  throw new IllegalStateException(" Les identifiants de connexion sont eronnés ");
}
```

Here's the controller method:

```js
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081")
@PostMapping(path = "/connect")
public String login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {    
    return userService.login(request);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv9bq.png)

Comment: Could you add the full request, including http method, request body, etc.
...and can you find and add the application log and post the stacktrace?

Comment: @tbjorch I've just added the controller method

Comment: I'm not understand your code. In the controller you call on registrationService the register method. But in the first snippet you call a login method. Please check if the method call in controller is correct

Comment: @AbilioCastro Yes, I'm sorry, I've just corrected it. Please check the controller again and kindly help me if you may.

Comment: Maybe you have to check your port mappings. It's very strange get server application up on port 100. Did you already verify if this port is not in use? Your frontend is really running on port 8081?

Answer (score 0):

you can add logger/system.out.println/debug code/enable console to see error
make sure you request body has all valid data while requesting